# What is the C# equivalent of Java's java/util/function/BiFunction?

Tags: java, c#, function, equivalent

In Java there is an interface called `BiFunction` with [this source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/function/BiFunction.java):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BiFunction<T, U, R> {
    R apply(T t, U u);

    default <V> BiFunction<T, U, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t, U u) -> after.apply(apply(t, u));
    }
}
```

And the [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) states that it works like this:

> Represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a
> result. This is the two-arity specialization of Function. This is a
> functional interface whose functional method is apply(Object, Object).

> `apply`
>
> `R apply(T t, U u)` Applies this function to the given arguments. Parameters: `t` - the first function argument `u` - the second function argument
> Returns: the function result

> `andThen`
>
> `default <V> BiFunction<T,U,V> andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)`
>
> Returns a composed function that first applies this
> function to its input, and then applies the after function to the
> result. If evaluation of either function throws an exception, it is
> relayed to the caller of the composed function. Type Parameters: `V` -
> the type of output of the after function, and of the composed function
> Parameters: `after` - the function to apply after this function is
> applied Returns: a composed function that first applies this function
> and then applies the after function Throws: `NullPointerException` - if
> `after` is null

I wanted to know how to implement this interface as a class or an extension method in `C#`, and is there a class for this in `C#` by default?

Comment: Maybe `System.Func<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using functional interfaces to represent functions like Java does, C# uses [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). There is a built in delegate - [`Func<T1,T2,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=net-5.0), that represents a function with 2 parameters and a non-void return value, just like `BiFunction` in Java.

To `apply` a delegate, you just can just call them like a function/method. Example:

```
Func<int, int, int> add = (x, y) => x + y;

// similar to: System.out.println(add.apply(1, 2));
Console.WriteLine(add(1, 2));
```

If you really want to write a word there, you can write `Invoke`:

```
add.Invoke(1, 2);
```

It doesn't have the `andThen` method, but you can write an extension method for that:

```
public static Func<T1, T2, R> AndThen<T1, T2, U, R>(this Func<T1, T2, U> bifunction, Func<U, R> andThen)
    => (x, y) => andThen(bifunction(x, y));
```

Comment: What about Apply method?

Comment: @MamarezaAlipour Ah I forgot to address that. You can just call delegates as if they are functions. You don't need an `apply` method, which is arguably quite verbose. See how I implemented `AndThen` by directly calling them?